# How to enable or disable an item in aTListView with dynamic appearance?

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a TListView with dynamic appearance, there are some items like text and images. I would like in runtime, disable or enable these items, depending on the situation.

I didn't find a reference on the internet until that moment. Thanks for the help ..

Ex:

```
ListView.Items.Clear;
x:=0
while not Query.eof do
begin
  Item := ListView.Items.Add;

  Listview.Items.AppearanceItem[x].Data['IdItem'] := x;
  Listview.Items.AppearanceItem[x].Data['Status'] := vStatus;
  if vStatus = 1 then   
     Listview.Items.ApperanceItm[x]....:= "enabled or disable";
  Query.next;
  x:=x+1;
end;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to inform which Delphi version and to include a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that the items are visible or not, depending on a condition.

You have to apply these changes in the OnUpdateObjects event handler with the following code e.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.ListViewUpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;const AItem: TListViewItem);
var txt : TListItemText;
    img : TListItemImage;
begin
  txt := TListItemText(Aitem.Objects.FindDrawable('Status'));
  if txt.Text='1' then
  begin
    img := TListItemImage(AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('ImageStatus')); // ImageStatus is the name of the TImageObjectAppearance you want to show or hide
    img.Visible := false;
    txt.Visible := false;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Roberto Zambrano has worked this solution as you expected?